# PageControl placing the marker in the position I want ios 9

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6, uipagecontrol

I am creating a screen of an application that contains inside a custom cell one pageControll. It is already working properly but by default his marker comes down the contentView. How can I make the marker in the position I say? In case a little but within the above contentView

this is my screen:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possible solutions.

1. Instead of adding the pageControl to the the cell's content view, add it instead as a child of the red view you have there.
2. In interface build add a constraint between the bottom of the content view and the pageControl.

Either should achieve the result you're looking for, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: the second possibility seems more feasible since it when I make the scrool on pageview she should change color. With the first option would be too complicated to accomplish this. As the second option you have any examples? I've never done this and the logic aprece me serta but have no idea how to get it.

Comment: This video is pretty old, but it covers the basics well. If you look around on youtube you'll find dozens of tutorials on autolayout.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3to5m3zuTEw